# Sending a message using a adhoc network

Tags: iphone, ios, p2p, gamekit, adhoc

Is it possible to send messages using an adhoc network between iOS devices?

Is there any documentation on how to do this?

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is what you're looking for :  [GKSession Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/GKSession)

Comment: right , but can we connect from IOS to android devices..

Comment: If you replicate or reverse engineer what GKSession does, yes, but the whole reason this functionality exists as an API is that it's a pain to implement.